# Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.'

Tags: vb.net

I'm coding a 'website' for a gym for homework and when I try to add a class to the listview I get the error "Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.'"

```
Private Sub BtnAddClass_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddClass.Click
   ListViewBasket.Items.Add(New ListViewItem({txtClassCode.Text, cmbClass.SelectedItem, (txtPrice.Text), cmbDuration.SelectedItem, CDbl(txtTotalPrice.Text)}))
   txtClassCode.Clear()
   cmbClass.SelectedIndex = -1
   cmbDuration.SelectedIndex = -1
   txtTotalPrice.Clear()
   txtPrice.Clear()
End Sub
```

I expected it to add a new class to the listview but the code doesn't work

Comment: What value is in your textbox exactly (txtTotalPrice.Text) ?

Comment: You might benefit from [learning how to use breakpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019) to debug this kind of issue. By knowing the value of `txtTotalPrice.Text` you'll give yourself a better chance at understanding what's going on. Good luck!

Comment: You haven't computed the txtTotalPrice yet.  So CDbl() goes "huh?".  It surely doesn't belong in that ListView column at all.

Answer (score 0):

Empty strings won't be cast to double by default, you need to use TryParse in the second row:

```
Double d = 0

Double.TryParse(txtTotalPrice.Text, d)

ListViewBasket.Items.Add(New ListViewItem({txtClassCode.Text, cmbClass.SelectedItem, txtPrice.Text, cmbDuration.SelectedItem, d)}))
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you used `TryParse` as an `If` expression then put the `ListViewBasket.Items.Add` method in its `True` block?

Comment: I mean, It's better if the method does not get called at all if the `Double` is of no use.